# Why getline skips first line?

Tags: c++

In the following code, `getline()` skips reading the first line.
I noted that when commenting the "`cin >> T`" line, it works normally. But I can't figure out the reason.

I want to read an integer before reading lines! How to fix that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int T, i = 1;
    string line;

    cin >> T;

    while (i <= T) {
        getline(cin, line);
        cout << i << ": " << line << endl;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
cin >> T;
```

This consumes the integer you provide on stdin.

The first time you call:

```
getline(cin, line)
```

...you consume the newline after your integer.

You can get `cin` to [**`ignore`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the newline by adding the following line after `cin >> T;`:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

(You'll need `#include <limits>` for [**`std::numeric_limits`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits))

Answer (score 4):

Most likely there is a newline in your input file, and that is being processed immediately, as explained on this page:

http://augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/iotips.html

You may want to call `cin.ignore()` to have it reject one character, but, you may want to read more of the tips, as there are suggestions about how to handle reading in numbers.

Comment: @Osama: It is well documented on that page. I've added a simple fix to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918451/why-getline-skips-first-line/5918484#5918484), but you should really read and understand the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This line only reads a number:

```
cin >> T;
```

If you want to parse user input you need to take into account they keep hitting <enter> because the input is buffered. To get around this somtimes it is simpler to read interactive input using getline. Then parse the content of the line.

```
std::string userInput;
std::getline(std::cin, userInput);

std::stringstream(userInput) >> T;
```