# C++ debugger skipping simple lines of code in console

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have problem with the code where the debugger I'm using (Visual C++ & Bloodshed Dev C++) where it simply skips a line of code or so where there's supposed to be input. Here's the code:

```
for(x = 0; x < TASKLIMIT; ++x)
{
    cout<<"Enter the name of a task: ";
    getline(cin, task[x].name);
    cout<<"Enter the priority of the task: ";
    cin>>task[x].priority;
    while (task[x].priority > 10 || task[x].priority < 1)
    {
        cout<<"Enter a number from 1-10: ";
        cin>>task[x].priority;
    }
    cout<<"Enter the estimated completion time of the task: ";
    cin>>task[x].completion;
    cout<<"Enter the deadline of the task: ";
    cin>>task[x].deadline;
}
```

the problem moves line occasionally first it was in the line

```
cin>>task[x].deadline;
```

then it moved to:

```
getline(cin, task[x].name);
```

when it got to the second iteration of the for loop

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What line of code is it skipping?

Comment: Most likely a dupe of 90% of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+getline+skipping

Comment: I edited it to show specific lines, sorry

Comment: You should always check your input to see if it's worked: `if (!(cin >> task[x].priority) { std::cerr << "error reading priority\n"; exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`... you may well have an earlier I/O error causing later `cin` statement to fall through, perhaps due to entering say a real number where an integer is expected - leaving the ".123" part on the stream, or failing to consume a newline.

Comment: thanks to chris...that was helpful, I just wish I knew exactly how, I'll have to do some research, thank you guys

Comment: The key here is to undersyand what `cin` reads and what it doesn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918451/why-getline-skips-first-line

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the release mode or debug mode?
If you are in release mode, assembly code are optimized. If you use that code to debug, it is always not moving line to line.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the following code:

```
cin.ignore();
cin.sync();

cout<<"Enter the name of a task: ";
getline(cin, task[x].name);
```

see how that works out for you. I always fall into similar traps and can usually solve it by clearing out the buffer.