# Getline ignoring first character of input

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm just starting with arrays in C++ and I'm having a problem getting the first character of an array.

This is my code,

1- I enter a name, such as "Jim"

```
char name[30];
cin.ignore();
cin.getline(name, 30);
```

2- Right away I try to cout the array

```
    cout<<"NAME:"<<name; // THIS PRINTS 'im'
```

I was sure it would print 'J'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just starting to learn, you should use `std::string` and `std::getline`. They'll make your life a lot easier. And by just starting to learn, I mean worry about how they work later, but still keep using them.

Comment: Anyway, it's possible you just ignored one character when there wasn't anything to ignore, so it ignored the first letter of your new input.

Comment: I realized I'm not getting the first character at all. Why can this be? I have the exact same code somewhere else and I'm getting the input right. I can't use std::getline simply because I haven't seen it in class, and I have to hand this as a project

Comment: You probably have leftover input to ignore in the other place. And what kind of class uses character arrays (or please don't say you use pointers) before `std::string`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is signature of cin.ignore:

```
istream& ignore (streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF);
```

So if you call ignore function without any parameters, it will ignore '1' char by default from input. In this case it ignored 'J'. Remove ignore call and you will get 'Jim'.

Comment: I see but I'm not sure I understand why this happens. I have the exact same code somewhere else, with the ignore and it doesn't skip the first character

Comment: @Liso22: Anywhere before the call to `getline` in this other code, do you have a call to `operator>>`?  As in: `cin >> something;` ?  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918451/why-getline-skips-first-line) for why the call to `ignore` was right for that case, but not in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove cin.ignore();

This ignores the first character, thus you miss the 'J'.

Answer (score 1):

I had this piece of code with the problem that it was eating the first character after the first cycle (first cycle was ok)

```
do{
    cout << endl << "command:> ";
    string cmdStr1="";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, cmdStr1);
    cout << "cin= " << cmdStr1 << endl; //For Debuging
    //...more code here
}while(1);
```

Output was:

command:> pos

cin= pos

command:> pos          ... from 2nd loop it started to delete the 1st character

cin= os

...

If "cin.ignore();" was commented then it resulted in a "segmentation fault":

command:> cin=

Segmentation fault

Solution working for me:

To move the "cin.ignore();" line just before the do-while loop.

```
cin.ignore();

      do{
            std::cout << endl << "command:> ";
            std::string cmdStr1="";
            std::getline(std::cin, cmdStr1);
            std::cout << "cin= " << cmdStr1 << endl; //For Debuging
            //...more code here
    }while(1);
```

Output was:

command:> pos

cin= pos

command:> pos

cin= pos

...

...

P.S. It was incredible hard to put code here... I am disappointment to continue collaborating.