# getline ignores first character of string input

Tags: c++

Why does C++'s `getline` function ignore the first character of my input?

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006401/getline-ignoring-first-character-of-input), the culprit was `cin.ignore()`, but I don't have the `cin.ignore()` function in my code.

Here's a very basic sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string user_input;

    cout << "input: ";
    cin >> user_input;
    getline(cin,user_input);

    cout << "length: " << user_input.length() << endl;
    cout << "your input: " << user_input << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, the output is totally wrong:

```
input: 1 2 3
length: 4
your input:  2 3
```

Obviously the length of the string, with spaces included, should be `5`, not `4`. You can also see that the 1st character of `user_input` is missing.

Can somebody explain to me why this code gives the wrong output and what I need to do to fix this problem? I've never worked with strings that contain spaces like this. I'm curious about what causes this problem to arise! :)

Comment: Haven't you consumed the first number with the `cin>>user_input`?

Answer (score 3):

`cin >> user_input` is the culprit. It's grabbing the input until the first space Get rid of that line of code and you should be all set with just the `getline(cin,user_input)`.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for explaining that to me. That's interesting. Dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 3):

`cin >> user_input;` is eating the first number.  Then `getline()` comes along and gets the rest of the input.  Remove `cin >> user_input;` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
cin >> user_input;
```

I'm not sure why you put that line there, but that reads and consumes the first space delimited string from `cin`. So it reads the 1. After that, `getline` reads the rest of the line, which is `" 2 3"`.

Answer (score -1):

just remove this line `cin >> user_input;` then your code will work.

Comment: Why repost the same information from existing answers that were posted years ago? This adds nothing new.