# Switch Statement Not Allowing First User Input

Tags: c++, switch-statement, getline

This function checks a two-dimensional char array and goes through each word in the array, using the size, searching for a `>` which will take it into a switch statement searching for cases.

I am having a problem in the switch statement, specifically with user input the first time the switch statement goes through the `default` case.

```
void parseWord(char story[][256], int size)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      char prompt[256][32];
      if (story[i][0] == '<')
      {
         switch (story[i][1])
         {
            case '#':
               story[i][0] = '\n';
               story[i][1] = 0;
               break;
            case '{':
               story[i][0] = ' ';
               story[i][1] = '\"';
               story[i][2] = 0;
               break;
            case '}':
               story[i][0] = '\"';
               story[i][1] = ' ';
               story[i][2] = 0;
               break;
            case '[':
               story[i][0] = ' ';
               story[i][1] = '\'';
               story[i][2] = 0;
               break;
            case ']':
               story[i][0] = '\'';
               story[i][1] = ' ';
               story[i][2] = 0;
               break;
            default:
               int p = 1;

               prompt[i][0] = (char)(toupper(story[i][1]));
               for (int j = 2; story[i][j] != '>'; j++)
               {
                  if (story[i][j] == '_')
                     prompt[i][p] = ' ';
                  else
                     prompt[i][p] = story[i][j];
                  p++;
               }

               cout << '\t' << prompt[i] << ": ";

               cin.getline(prompt[i], 32);

               int z = 0;
               for (int t=0; prompt[i][t] != '\0'; t++)
               {
                  story[i][t] = prompt[i][t];
                  z++;
               }

               story[i][z] = 0;


         }
      }
   }

   return;
}
```

`cin.getline(prompt[i], 32);` is having a problem the first time it is ran.

This is the output I currently get when I run my function, with user input in *'s:

```
 Web site name:  Verb: *run*
 Plural noun: *dogs*
 Plural noun: *cats*
 Proper noun: *Jimmy*
 Adjective: *smart*
 Noun: *table*
 Noun: *desk*
 Boolean operator: *xor*
 Noun: *shoe*
 Favorite website: *google.com*
 Another website: *yahoo.com*
 Adjective: *cold*
 Emoticon: *:P*
```

As you can see, the `cin.getline(prompt[i], 32)` is skipped when the code is ran and right away goes to the next Prompt and asks for user input. This is not making what is entered in `Verb` equal to what `Web site name` should be, but is not allowing anything to be entered into `Web site name` and making it empty. `Verb` is still equal to, in this case "run".

Why is the switch statement seemingly skipping the `cin.getline(prompt[i], 32)` statement the first time around? All the times the `default` case is ran after the first seem to be working as expected and I can't see or understand why user input would not be allowed the first time the `default` case is ran in the switch.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why getline skips first line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918451/why-getline-skips-first-line)

Answer (score 0):

I found that in other functions in my program that I received input with `cin`. Looking at [Why getline skips first line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918451/why-getline-skips-first-line) I saw that `cin` and `cin.getline()` don't work well together. After trying `cin.ignore()` statements (which fixed this problem but created many others) I decided to exclusively get all input using `cin.getline()`. All inputs work now.