# In c++ ifstream reads nothing in a line

Tags: c++

I'm copying a part of my code that tries to save data from a text that is presented line per line. a, b, e, f are strings while the other variables are ints. The problem is that in e it saves nothing and in f saves the part corresponding to e. After this I try to read more data but always saves nothing in e. Please help
.
**strong text**

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <fstream>
        #include <string>
        using namespace std;
        int main(){
          ifstream archivote;
          archivote.open(vuelos.txt);
          string line,a,b,e,f;
          int ca,cb,cc,cd,ce,da,db,dc,dd,de,q;
          while(getline(archivote, line)){
             getline(archivote,a);
             getline(archivote,b);
             archivote >> ca;
             archivote >> cb;
             archivote >> cc;
             archivote >> cd;
             archivote >> ce;
             archivote >> da;
             archivote >> db;
             archivote >> dc;
             archivote >> dd;
             archivote >> de;
             getline(archivote,e);
             getline(archivote,f);
             cout << a << '\n' <<b  << '\n'<< ca  << '\n'<< cb
             << '\n'<< cc  << '\n'<< cd  << '\n'<< ce << '\n' 
             << da  << '\n'<< db  << '\n'<< dc  << '\n'<< dd << 
             '\n' << de  << '\n'<< e  << '\n'<< f;
             return 0;
       }
       }
```

And the text

```
      Mexico
      Puebla
      12
      12
      2000
      12
      13
      12
      12
      2000
      12
      22
      AeroMexico
      1234
      Buenos Aires
      Panama
      02
      12
      2000
      03
      12
      02
      12
      2000
      05
      23
      Viva Aerobus
      1592
```

Comment: Useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918451/why-getline-skips-first-line

Comment: So `Mexico` goes into `line`, `Puebla` into `a`, `12` into `b`, which is probably not what you meant. Why again are you reading into `line` variable that you are not using anywhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why getline skips first line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918451/why-getline-skips-first-line)

Comment: It also happens with reading files?